# ionic hide splashscreen after api call are completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I want to keep the Splashscreen displayed until my application end-up to fetch multiple data from different Api call. The code to hide the Splashscreen is based on a Timer and I don't want that:

```
 app.run(function($cordovaSplashscreen) {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $cordovaSplashscreen.hide()
  }, 5000)
 })
```

The current behaviour that I have it's a Splashscreen displaying for 5 seconds and then come's up the first view in a blank page, only after few seconds, the data will be visible in my view.

My question is: How can I add the logic in my app.js to hide the Splashscreen only when the API call are done, so that way the user will see the first view with all the data ready to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is waiting for all requests to be finished with `$q.all(promises)` using `angularjs` built-in promise library. Within the success function you can call `$cordovaSplashscreen.hide()` in your controller  to hide the splashscreen like [user46772](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35701560/5159481) already mentioned. Example code:

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="AppController"></body>
```

**app.js**

```
var module = angular.module( "app", [ "ngCordova", "yourServices" ] )

module.config( ... );
module.run( ... );
module.controller( "ApplicationController", ApplicationController );

function ApplicationController( $cordovaSplashscreen, $q, apiCallService ) {

    loadData();

    function loadData() {

        $q.all( apiCallService.loadFoo1, apiCallService.loadFoo2, apiCallService.loadFoo3)
             .then( onSuccess, onError );

        function onSuccess() {
            $cordovaSplashscreen.hide()
        }

        function onError() {
            // do something useful else
        }
    }
}
```

**yourServices.js**

```
angular
    .module( "yourServices", [ "$http" ] )
    .factory( "apiCallService", apiCallService );

function apiCallService( "$http" ) {
    return {
        loadFoo1: loadFoo1,
        loadFoo2: loadFoo2,
        loadFoo3: loadFoo3
    }

    function loadFoo1() {
        return $http.get( "yourAPI" );
    }

    ...
}
```

Be aware that this code is not a working example. But it should explain how you could proceed to solve your issue. Furthmore you have to think about what should happen if one of your requests fails at the `onError()` function.

Additionally you should wrap the code into the [`onDeviceReady`](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) event. Assuming you are using `ionic` you can make use of this piece of code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready( loadData );
```

Do not forget to inject the `$ionicPlatform` into the controller function.

Answer (score 1):

On run block, I don't see any function call to fetch the data. If your API  is promise based, you can hide the splashscreen on success or error function.  But I wouldn't encourage you to call it from the run block either, because it might cause problems that are hard to detect down the line.

I would suggest using `ui-router` and try the resolve function. This function is loaded before the transition into the view.

Comment: Yes, sorry if it was confusing but the Api call are made in an external Factory dedicated to it, I inject this Factory into my controller witch need to display the data, but I need the whole logic to maybe (If possible) call my Factory when the Splashscreen is displayed and then hide it based on the success promise like you suggested.